# how to visualize age gender attributes of person in bipartite graph of person with diseases?

Tags: r, igraph

I need some help regarding modeling a multi columns data. I have .csv file, which contain an edge list of persons their age, gender, location and diseases they are suffering from. I have drawn a bipartite graph of a person with diseases. How can i read age, gender and location in bipartite graph using igraph? I have tried the code below but it only takes 2 columns of csv to draw a network. Can anyone help how to read person attribute like age, gender and location in this case?

```
 Person Diseases    Gender  Age 
 John   Asthma      M      25
 Alice  pneumonia   F      35
 Bob    Typhoid     M      40
 Jane   TB          F      21
.. . .. ...

getwd()
datafile <- "/d.csv"
d_el <- read.csv(datafile)
d_el <- d_el[, 1:4 ]
head(d_el)
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(d_el, directed = FALSE)
plot(g, layout = pref.layout, 
vertex.color="black"
)
```

how to visualize age and gender in this network? i have used these line of codes

```
V(g)$age <- d_el$Age
V(g)$gender <- d_el$Gender
```

but this is not useful for network modelling i want to visualize these age gender attributes in network graph ? help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better to use assortativity coefficient to read these attributes in network analysis

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to visualize gender by node color and age by node size.

```
plot(g, vertex.color=V(g)$gender, vertex.size=V(g)$age)
```

[image]

Comment: please share the full code like this  V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$age == 1, "lightblue", "orange")

Comment: you dont necessarily have to add the color attribute to a vertex, you can directly provide the colors while plotting too.

Comment: Problem solved.. Thank you so much. suggest how to show location attribute ??

Comment: perhaps associating with some other attributes such as shape of the vertex will do

Comment: location can be included in graph if graph will be tripartite ? how to draw tripartite network ?